# how can I get a df from a complex str?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got a str by using the requests.get(url) , it is a huge text, the abbreviations are as follows:

```
[{"id":0001,"stock_id":"hk00688","stock_name":"abc"},
 {"id":0002,"stock_id":"hk00689","stock_name":"def"},
 {"id":0003,"stock_id":"hk00690","stock_name":"ghi"}]
```

I want to get the df as it:

```
id    stock_id   stock_name
0001  hk00688    abc
0002  hk00689    def
0003  hk00690    ghi
```

but I got two difficult points need to help:

1, it is a str but the "list of dict", I don't know how to deal with it;

2, when I change the str to "list of dict", Is there is a simple function that converts to df， instead of using a for loop？

Comment: first ``json.loads`` to convert string to python object then call ``pd.DataFrame`` on the result.

Comment: yes, I get it ,thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server's response is clearly JSON, which is very easy to parse:

```py
response = requests.get(url)
df = pd.DataFrame(response.json())
```

Comment: thank you very much , I have done it.
by the way, I used json.loads(response) to solve it. because the there is a error : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'
did I missed something?

Comment: Did you set `response = request.get(url).text` earlier in the code?